# JPA - SpringData - Column 1 equals column 2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a `spring-boot` project with `Spring-Data`. I want to do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_1 = column_2
```

How can I do it using the `SpringData` `JpaRepository`? I tried to find a way like:

`MyTable findByColumn1...Column2()` without any luck

Answer (score 5):

There is no default way to do that you have to use the @Query annotation like this:

```
@Query("select e from entity e where e.column1 = e.column2")
List<Entity> findByColumn1EqualsColumn2();
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was doing. I just wanted to see if there is a default way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna use default method only you can use

```
List<Entity> findByColumn1AndColumn2(@Param("column1") String column1, @Param("column2") String column2);
```

And then passing the same parameter for column1 and column 2

i.e.

```
String column= "abc";
List<Entity> entitylist=repository.findByColumn1AndColumn2(column,column);
```

Comment: No...that is not the requirement...I do NOT know the param1 and param2 values..I want to find the ones that have the SAME value regardless of the value